# Integrated powershell core not working in vscode terminal

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code

In vscode extension marketplace , I am getting the option of powershell preview version and not the stable version. Is there any other alternate to solve this issue?

[image: powershell showing up error]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In **VS Code**:

1. Open **Extensions**
2. Select **PowerShell** extension
3. Click the **Manage** cog-wheel (bottom-right corner)
4. Click **Install Another Version...** from the menu
5. Choose a version you feel comfortable with.

*Note: I highly recommend running VS Code elevated (run as Administrator) to ensure installation of new extensions run smoothly.*

Hope this helps.